# How to georeference/convert an image to GeoTiff using Gdal without upper and lower coordinates

Tags: python, gdal, georeferencing

I have an image that i want to convert to GeoTiff(Georeferenced image), but i don't have upper and lower coordinates to map for that image. However i have the coordinates at specific pixel value of the image. e.g. 5,10 position on the image has 73.333, 33.33. I have four of such pixel values, and their respective coordinates. How can i use GDAL to geo-reference my image using these values of coordinates at specific pixel ?

**Update:**

I need to write this in Python using gdal. I have the script working using the corner coordinates for the image, but i want to do with coordinates at specific pixel values.

```
xmin, ymax, xmax, ymin = data['config']['xmin'], data['config']['ymax'] ,data['config']['xmax'] ,data['config']['ymin'],

input_ds = gdal.Open(input_file)
output_image = 'output_image.tif'

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
x_res = (xmax - xmin) / input_ds.RasterXSize

   

    y_res = (ymin - ymax) / input_ds.RasterYSize
    geotransform = (xmin, x_res, 0, ymax, 0, y_res)

    # Set the output dataset options
    output_ds_opts = {
        'format': output_format,
        'outputBounds': [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax],
        'outputSRS': f'EPSG:{target_epsg}',
        'outputType': input_ds.GetRasterBand(1).DataType,
        'creationOptions': ['COMPRESS=LZW']
    }

    output_ds = gdal.Translate(output_image, input_ds, **output_ds_opts)
```

Comment: Add ground control points `-gcp` with gdal_translate or gdal_edit. Some programs like QGIS can open the image with ground control points directly but for others you can make a normal georeferenced image with gdalwarp `gdalwarp input_with_gcp.tif output.tif`

Comment: I am writing the code in Python. How can do that in python using gdal?

Comment: Gdal_edit is a Python script, maybe you can use that as an example https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_edit.py.

Comment: I don't quite understand how can i use that to achieve the purpose that i am trying to achieve.

Comment: maybe you can share some code snippet or code example that i can understand better?

Comment: Maybe you can find something from old answers, like https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206544/in-python-gdal-how-to-add-ground-control-point-to-geotiff-image-by-using-gdal-tr.